# data treatment before or after train/test sets split?

Tags: data-transformation, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a variable in my data with NA values and I want to apply knn input. Should I do it before or after split the data in train and test set?
If I do it after, each set will only use the values in it, that is, I may be losing some info? So my guts go to do it before splitting Is that right?

What is better and why?

Comment: If I get your question correctly, you are trying to replace NA values in your data using some procedure based on knn? If so, I would recommend you replace the values after you split the data, and apply the same replacement model calculated on training data to your test data.

Comment: So instead of doing this: data<- kNN(data) training<-data[inTrain,] 
testing<-data[-inTrain,]        I do this: training<-data[inTrain,]    testing<-data[-inTrain,]    training<- kNN(training)       testing<- kNN(training)